# How to catch response properly from Hapi server.inject

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, hapi

I want to have a catch for errors and success for the server.inject method as currently if it throws an error, it is not caught by the function doing the inject, so how would I do that with a function like this

I am using hapi (17.x)

```
server.inject({
  method: 'POST',
  url: `/xxx`,
  payload: {
    x: x
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in hapi 17 you need to use async await. with that, you can use try/catch.

```
try {
  await server.inject(options)
} catch(e) {
  //handle error here
}
```

Comment: @Ashh post a new question so that you can post your code in its entirety